# Realm data synchronization

Tags: swift, realm

Please, explain the behavior.

If I want to update some data using Realm I have to do something like this:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
  let theDog = realm.objects(Dog.self).filter("age == 1").first
  try! realm.write {
    theDog!.age = 3
  }
}
```

But what happens if I just do this: `theDog!.age = 3` ? will theDod data be out of sync? How can I update this element later?

```
try! realm.write {
//what I have to write here?
  }
```

Is there any way to force sync each element changing? Is there any disadvantage to use force sync if it exists?

Comment: Define "force sync", although I think you're lucky and Realm actually already does that for you automatically.

Comment: So, why in the manual it wrapped by realm.write block?

Comment: Transactional modification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please excuse my Swift if I mess it up, I'm not too familiar with the syntax.

While I know this is the example code, I don't actually like it much.

```
let realm = try! Realm()
  let theDog = realm.objects(Dog.self).filter("age == 1").first
  try! realm.write {
    theDog!.age = 3
  }
}
```

The query should be inside the transaction block to ensure that you're modifying the latest version of the object.

```
let realm = try! Realm()
  try! realm.write {
    let theDog = realm.objects(Dog.self).filter("age == 1").first
    theDog!.age = 3
  }
}
```

Now, I think your question is why `realm.write {` is needed. It's because you can modify managed RealmObjects only in a transaction.

Transaction is required to ensure that a particular thread's Realm instance is switched to "write mode", and there can only be one Realm instance in "write mode" at a given time. As a result of this, a version seen by a given Realm instance will always remain consistent, and doesn't change - only when Realm syncs itself to a new version.

This is how Realm is designed so that you can create new versions of the Realm easily on a background thread, which then automatically syncs up to other Realm instances.

When a transaction is committed, then when this change occurs, a message is sent to other threads *(if they can receive a message, anyways - requires an event loop, for example the UI thread has one)* telling the Realm instances on those threads to update themselves; and to call all change listeners of all result sets and managed RealmObjects to indicate that they've too been updated (if they changed with this transaction).

---

So to answer your question, the properties you change are changed in all RealmObjects that belong to the same object.

```
let realm = try! Realm()
  let originalDog = realm.objects(Dog.self).filter("age == 1").first
  try! realm.write {
    let theDog = realm.objects(Dog.self).filter("age == 1").first
    theDog!.age = 3
  }
  // assuming there is only 1 dog with age==1, 
  // originalDog!.age will be 3
}
```

I think the "force sync" you speak of is a primary feature of Realm.

Comment: This is a great answer. Realm is ACID compliant and uses an MVCC architecture, which necessitates the support for transactions. When you commit a transaction, this means all copies of that object will update (automatically on other threads if that thread has a runloop attached), including any remote copy of the object if you are using Realm Mobile Platform.